# Show start date of week(ie. sunday date) from week number in angular js

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

```
<div class="weekLabel">{{weeknumber | date filter}}</div>
```

Input:

weeknumber - 28

I want the below result

Start date of week - July 10th (ie. sunday)

```
<div class="weekLabel">July 10th</div>
```

And also, if the year(2017), week number(2) - it will show the start date of week 2017.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using moment:

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.week = 12;
});

app.filter('getMondayOfWeek', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? moment().day("Monday").week(input).format("MMM Do") : "";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{week | getMondayOfWeek}}
</div>
```

Comment: k. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: for using years you ve to edit the filter and add a parameter, then check if the year is present and call .year(theyear) before call .format